# Storing Words From File Into An Array In C

Tags: c, arrays, store, fgets

```
char c; 
int i=0;   
while( ( c = fgetc(file) ) != EOF )
{   
      fgets (array[i].word, 101, file);
      printf(array[i].word);
      i++;
}
```

The variable `array` is a `struct` type and that `struct` has the field: `char word[101]`. `file` is the file that we are reading from.

The text file contains:

```
Hey You
Look!
```

But my output of my program says:

```
ey You
ook!
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `fgetc()`?

Comment: Note that you are reading whole lines (if they're shorter than 100 characters) into the `word` element of the structure.  This is not the same as reading words.

Comment: oh ya, you're right. Maybe I should use another function. Maybe: fscanf

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know why this is happening?

Yes, you are reading the first character with your `fgetc`.

Use `while(1)` and the return code of `fgets` to determine if you are at the end of your input file.

Answer (score 2):

I think your line:

```
c = fgetc(file)
```

gets the first character of each line, which is why it is missing.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `fgetc(c)` consumes the first character from the buffer.

Change your code to read the strings using `fgets`, and check the return value for `NULL` to know when the file has been read completely:

```
while (fgets(array[i].word, 101, file) != NULL) {
    i++;
}
```

You can further shorten this by dropping the check for `NULL`, and embedding the `i++` into the array expression, like this:

```
while (fgets(array[i++].word, 101, file))
    ;
```

Note that the body of the loop is now empty.

Note: you need to watch out for undefined behavior when the file contains more lines than the number of elements in `array`.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually consuming the start of each line with the `(c = fgetc(file))` note that fgetc actually pulls a character off the input buffer, and thus is lost when you read the rest of the string.

In order to check for EOF without consuming chars, it is better to use `while(!file.eof())`

Comment: There is no `file.eof()` method (this is C we are talking about), and checking for EOF in the loop condition is not a good idea as the EOF flag is only set *after* trying to read past the end of the file.